# Removing x axis tooltip in apex charts

Tags: charts, tooltip, apexcharts

I am using ApexCharts to show some stats. I wanted to hide the x-axis tooltip which is marked in red in the image[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
options = {
  xaxis: {
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}
```

https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#tooltip

Comment: how to remove tooltip where "SAMPLE A" (tooltip over the chart area)?

Comment: you save my life

Comment: lives_saved += 1

Answer (score 2):

**In another way, you can hide Xaxis using:**

```
xaxis: {
  labels: {
    show: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

xaxis: {
tooltip: {
enabled: false
},
labels: {
show: true
}
},

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the above actually answer the OPs question. Based on their image and question they just wanted to remove the x-axis value at the bottom. You can do that by using CSS as follows:

```
.apexcharts-xaxistooltip-bottom {
  display: none;
}
```